# Using ekf_localization_node from robot_localization package for IMU only navigation

Tags: imu, navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a pretty high quality IMU (VN-100) for which I want to test the performance with IMU-only EKF  filter.  I have setup my system inspired this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/232794/can-i-use-robot_localization-package-with-only-imu-data-if-i-couldhow-to-config-the-package/).
However, I am experiencing the issue that the resulting `/filtered/odometry` shows zeros for linear displacements x,y and z.
Any hints or suggestions would be very welcome.  Thanks in advance.
I am setting up the system as follows:`imu_ekf.launch` :

```
 <launch>    
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="bl_imu" args="0 0 0 1.5708 0 3.1416 base_link imu" />    
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find imu_vn_100)/launch/imu_only_ekf.yaml" />
     <param name="odom_used" value="false"/>
      <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
      <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>        
  </node>
</launch>
```

`imu_only_efk.yaml`:

```
frequency: 50
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: false
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link #base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
imu0: /imu/imu
imu0_config: [true, true, true,
              true,  true,  true,
              true, true, true,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
use_control: false
stamped_control: false
control_timeout: 0.2
control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Cheers...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281204/using-ekf_localization_node-from-robot_localization-package-for-imu-only-navigation/) by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't say for certain what's wrong unless you post sample IMU messages (please do), but I note the following:

- Is your IMU topic really `imu/imu`?
- You have every single variable set to *true* for your IMU configuration, but I'm guessing it doesn't actually provide position (the first three *true* variables) or linear velocity (the seventh through the ninth *true* variables).
- Get rid off all of the `_threshold` parameters. Those are advanced parameters that should only be used once you have the rest of the system functioning.
- It won't make any difference, but you still have `robot_pose_ekf` parameters in your launch file.
- Finally, I have never seen IMU-only state estimation produce anything usable. Double-integration of linear acceleration is going to make your life unpleasant, unless your IMU (or you) are actively handling biases.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-09-26**:
I got the same problem . My robot frame is `/thrbot/base_link` and IMU frame is `thrbot/imu_link` .Any help?